# FadeIn with javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fadein

I have this code:

```
document.getElementById('showRtb').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('rtb').style.display="inline-table";    
});

document.getElementById('hideRtb').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('rtb').style.display="none";    
});
```

but now I want without jquery effect to make FadeIn animation, just with javascript. Without css3 and without jquery. Is that possible?

Comment: Given that jQuery is written in javascript, of course it is possible.  I'd suggest you either look for the jQuery source code (where they define their method), or search for a tutorial that builds something similar.

Comment: I try to find something similar but everwhere is jquery based

Comment: Really? because searching "fadein without jquery" I found code in literally 1 minute.  http://jsfiddle.net/2Pd6e/16/

Comment: @Andrew _"Without css3 and without jquery."_ Why are  `jquery`, `css3` tags included at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()`, `getComputedStyle()`. See also [`The`Animation`interface`](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/#the-animation-interface)

```js
var rtb = document.getElementById("rtb"),
  timer = null;

document.getElementById("showRtb").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rtb.style.opacity != 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    rtb.style.display = "inline-table";
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      rtb.style.opacity = +rtb.style.opacity + .10;
      if (+getComputedStyle(rtb).getPropertyValue("opacity") >= 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 100)
  }
});

document.getElementById("hideRtb").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rtb.style.opacity != 0) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      rtb.style.opacity = +rtb.style.opacity - .10;
      if (+getComputedStyle(rtb).getPropertyValue("opacity") <= 0) {
        rtb.style.display = "none";
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 100)
  }
});
```

```css
#rtb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: olive;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="showRtb">show</button>
<button id="hideRtb">hide</button>
<br>
<div id="rtb"></div>
```